# CodeIgniter site in subdirectory, htaccess file maybe interfering with htaccess file in main directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, url-rewriting

In my CodeIgniter site (hosted on GoDaddy), navigating to any page but the index gives me this error:

> No input file specified.

Googling around, it seems like the cause must have something to do with my .htaccess situation.  The way this is set up, and maybe this can eventually change, is that my CI site is in a subdirectory of the main domain.  The CI site and main domain each have their own .htaccess files.  The CI htacess file is located in the applications folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /SubDomain/index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here's the main htaccess file is two levels up from the CI one, reading thusly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.MainDomain.org/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I am afraid these two sets of re-write rules are conflicting with each other and I really have no idea what to do about it.  I can alter either htaccess file and would really like to get them working together in peace and harmony.  It's also possible, however, that this has nothing whatsoever to do with htaccess.

Comment: The second bunch of rewrite rules simply enable SSL security on unsecure connections. It shouldn't affect the CodeIgniter rules in any way.

Comment: I suppose that means I'm barking up the wrong tree with the htaccess files.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to remember how I solved this issue, but I do remember having the same problem while trying to install CI into a subfolder (some time ago). I think a combination of changes to the .htaccess file and the index.php file solved it for me. Maybe you can find a guide on Google or someone else may have more specific advice?

Comment: Have you updated the base_url config parameter ($config['base_url']) in config/config.php? If you're using site_url or anything to generate the appropriate links, it will be linking to the wrong place.

Comment: Do you have the main site and the subdomain set up as separate sites in the virtual hosts?

Comment: Resolved!  It was a combination of the accepted answer below, and the GoDaddy install tips I found here:  https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installaton-Tips

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CI `.htaccess` shouldn't be in the application folder; it should be in the root of the`SubDomain` folder. e.g. `/public_html/SubDomain/.htaccess`

Also, in that `.htaccess`, you need to set the `RewriteBase`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /SubDomain
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: _Thank You_.  This seems to have done the trick, in conjunction with this stuff here: github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installaton-Tips

Comment: Thanks, you have safed my half of day... :-)

Comment: I have url like this : http://dashboard.site.com/app/dashboard/test but its not working 

http://dashboard.site.com/app/index.php/dashboard/test -> this is working

could you please help?