# base url is not working ? 404 error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this config on my codeigniter file :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://kandanghosting.com/mtma/';
```

and i set my folder like this in my server
[image]

but still get this error

> 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

my htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

my routes :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

my completed config :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://kandanghosting.com/mtma/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';


$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Comment: Did you created that path while adding new domain in cPanel ? Just put a simple `index.html` file in same path after that try `http://kandanghosting.com` and `http://kandanghosting.com/mtma/` let me know which url display your plane html page.

Comment: ok.. u can acces this url ..  kandanghosting.com/mtma

its online .. u can see it

Comment: its shows 404. so we need to evaluate `config.php` to understand what's wrong. Do you have `.htaccess` file in same folder, if so just delete temporary and retry ?

Comment: @MuhammadMuqorrobin I can see the site and access this site menu. What you want ? project have in inside of the mtma folder

Comment: You don't have any non-existent controller set as the default controller in your `routes.php` , right ? 
Like `$route['default_controller'] = 'login';`

Comment: ok i ll edit my question .. i will add routes and htaccess

Comment: Have you followed codeigniter file and class naming way http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: its work when i try in localhost , but not when i upload to my server kandanghosting.com

Comment: project have in inside of mtma folder ? pls send the localhost your url

Comment: @MuhammadMuqorrobin you deploying CI in sub directory. So update your `.htaccess` as shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352995/codeigniter-site-in-subdirectory-htaccess-file-maybe-interfering-with-htaccess)

Comment: If is a subdomian try `$config['base_url'] = 'http://mtma.kandanghosting.com/';`

Comment: Are you sure the Controller home exists in you `application/controllers` folder as Home.php? Secondly what are you loading in `index()` function of the controller Home. May be the view file is not present in `application/views` folder. Third, in some hosting servers naming `home.php` will not work. It may throw either 404 error or `Empty File` error message. So ensure you renamed it as `Home.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your route

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
```

Comment: Lower case `$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`  best on routes.php default_controller

Comment: @BIBINJOHN And you don't need to create another answer just edit your first answer.

Comment: I have solved this problem, please just make few changes

1- all controller class name should start with capital letter. i mean first letter of class should be capital . eg we have controler with class name Pages

so it should be Pages not pages

2- save the controller class Pages as  Pages.php not pages.php

so first letter must be capital

same for model, model class first letter should be capital and also save model class as Pages_model.php not page_model.php

hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: @MuhammadMuqorrobin look at this will be help full http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

add this code part to your controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));

    }
```