# htaccess rewrite based on IP or domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using Codeigniter, now the rewrite is working fine for accessing using domain name, here is the default Codeigniter htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But I want to make it able to access using IP address as well and I host my website in a shared hosting with cPanel, so the IP address will be something like this: `http://11.11.11.11/~username`. But it just not working when I access using IP, I had tried adding a RewriteBase and also something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ~username/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^~username/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

but non of them work. Anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: what was the RewriteBase you used?

Comment: @antirealm I tried to add `RewriteBase /~username/` but still not working.

Comment: here is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352995/codeigniter-site-in-subdirectory-htaccess-file-maybe-interfering-with-htaccess

Comment: @MehmetSoylu nope my website was in the root folder, I just want to make it accessible using both domain and IP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found the solution, I should check the host so that RewriteBase only will work properly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /~username/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.11 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ping,

Unfortunately, you can not use IP as host while you'r on shared hosting. Share hosting shared single IP for multiple websites.

You need dedicated hosting or VPS for your purpose.